# Gammu: can not access sim card

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gammu, huawei-mobile-services

I tried to use a `Huawei E173` on my `Raspberry Pi 3` and so far it kind of worked. When I run `sudo gammu getsecuritystatus` it says that I have to enter my `SIM-PIN`. When I do so it says that everything is ok when putting the command, however, when I now try to send an SMS, it says `"Can not access SIM card."`.

I don't get it. First it seems to be able to communicate with the SIM and then it says that it can't.

When I run `sudo gammu --identify` after entering the PIN, I even get a `SIM IMSI`, so it seems to be able to talk to the SIM but I just can't get the SMS sending to work.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the SIM card work on other device? It can be that it is faulty. If you want to look deeper, please see [how to report bugs in Gammu](https://wammu.eu/support/bugs/), the logs might help to understand what is going on.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. "Unfortunately" the sim works fine. :( I don't know what else could be the problem... I will look into your link, thanks! :)

Comment: I now tried the debugging into a log file.
Here's the link: http://textuploader.com/dtf4t

Comment: Can you try upgrading Gammu? We have fixed several things for Huawei devices recently...

Comment: Good hint! Thanks a lot! Will do and report back! :)

Comment: Nope, I can't. It's already the latest version. Maybe something broke while fixing things for Huawei?

Comment: From the log I can see you have 1.33.0 which is almost four years old, latest one is 1.38.1, see https://wammu.eu/download/gammu/

Comment: weird, i tried "sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade gammu"... Gotta take a closer look into this!

Comment: You can install newer version from stretch, see this example for instructions how to install packages from it (just install gammu instead of deluge): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/59436/59659

Comment: Now I am getting "Failed to get SMSC number from phone." and the log says this:
http://textuploader.com/dti34

:/ Seems to be the same error in the log.

Comment: Tried "sudo gammu getsmsc 1"
Getting "Can not access SIM card."

So frustrating... according to a guide, the Huaweis are supposed to just work with Gammu. :(

Comment: I'd really say this has something to do with the SIM card, can you try different one in the modem?

Comment: I will try a different one (brand new T-Mobile sim) tomorrow again and report back but this sim is working perfectly in a dumb phone, an iPhone 5 and an iPhone 7. :(

Comment: Some devices are picky about SIM card, but indeed it's not that likely, I just want to rule out this problem.

Comment: Tried another SIM card and I get the same result. :/
http://txt.do/dra7q
This one is also definitely working and brand new (3 month old).

Maybe, if were stuck here, which I am afraid of, you could recommend me a usb modem that 100% works with gammu? I don't need LTE or such, just want to be able to send/receive text messages.
(Although I even just bought this Huawei-Stick because another guide said that they work perfectly with Gammu -_-)

Comment: People have quite good experiences with the Huawei devices, that's why I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work for you. Another option is that your device is faulty... As for other brand of devices, I know people using Siemens/Cinterion ES75, but I'm not sure if that's still being produced.

Comment: Hm, I see... any other suggestion then? :(

Comment: Anyone have a suggestion for a good, proven to be working USB modem?